# How do i change the colour of the status bar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

I've added a CollapsingToorbar, kept `android:foreground=#bd1212` . But when it collapses the status bar colour becomes the default colour. 
Can someone please tell me how to change the colour of the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

The property "contentScrim" is what you are looking for:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/place_activity_coordinator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF">
        ...
        ...
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/place_activity_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="#8000" <!-- This color is what you need to change -->
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsing_toolbar_expanded"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsing_toolbar_collapsed"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: I did try changing the contentScrim property. That doesn't do it. The same applies for a normal Toolbar. Changing its colour doesn't change the status bar colour. I've been trying to find the property that changes the status bar colour.